# How to change legend text color in leaflet for R?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, legend

I created a leaflet map in R Shiny. The problem is that the legend text color is very bright. I need to change the text color but don't find any option in leaflet legend for changing the legend text color.[image]

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducible example,...

Answer (score 2):

Nina!

As you can see from `?addLegend()`, there are several parameters that may suit you:

> pal: the color palette function, generated from colorNumeric(),
>   colorBin(), colorQuantile(), or colorFactor()
>
> colors: a vector of (HTML) colors to be used in the legend if pal is
>   not provided
>
> opacity: the opacity of colors

For example (from here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html):

```
qpal <- colorQuantile("RdYlBu", your_dataset$your_variable, n = 5)

addLegend(pal = qpal, values = ~your_variable, opacity = 1)
```

Best!